# How to fix cost aggregation error in Boto3 - Unknown parameter in input: "AggregateOn"

Tags: boto3

I need the total `UnblendedCost`, yet get the error upon adding the `AggregateOn` line below:

```py
import boto3
import pprint

client = boto3.client('ce')

response = client.get_cost_and_usage_with_resources(
    Granularity='HOURLY',
    Metrics=["UnblendedCost"],
    TimePeriod={
        'Start': '2021-12-28',
        'End': '2021-12-29'
    },
    Filter={
        "Dimensions": {
            "Key": "SERVICE",
            "Values": ["Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute"]
        },
        "Dimensions": {
            "Key": "RESOURCE_ID",
            "Values": ["i-024e2f80465246927"]
        }
    },
    # GroupBy=[{
    #     "Type": "DIMENSION",
    #     "Key": "RESOURCE_ID"
    # }],
    AggregateOn='UnblendedCost')

pprint.pprint(response)
```

Error:

`botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input: "AggregateOn", must be one of: TimePeriod, Granularity, Filter, Metrics, GroupBy, NextPageToken`

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage_with_resources) the function you use does not have a keyword-argument named `AggregateOn`. Therefore you get the error rejecting the unknown parameter.

Comment: Since you already specify *UnblendedCost* as the `Metrics` I would assume you should look into the `GroupBy` parameter (which you have commented out) to achieve the desired aggregation.